# Read DTD or Schema and list all valid child elements or attributes for a given element

Tags: c#, java, c++, xml, schema

I want to develop an application something like XML editor.. providing intellisense like feature when user types an element, the application will read the DTD or schema and list the valid child elements and attributes (something like Oxygen XML Editor).

Is there an API that i can get this done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with an API that performs this task.

If you choose to implement this yourself, however, here's a couple of thoughts:

- An XML schema is itself an XML file, that is structured according to the meta-schema. You can easily use one of the existing APIs to unmarshal a schema into an object structure that you can easily work with in-memory.
- A DTD is not an XML structure, but any DTD can be represented as a simple schema. Therefore you should try and find a way to convert a DTD into a schema (and apply your schema solution).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You might find [XSD4J](http://dynvocation.selfip.net/xsd4j/) useful:

> XSD4J is a library to parse XML Schema
>   files into a structure of Java
>   objects, convert those back into an
>   XML DOM tree (and hence plain text)
>   again, and allow for performing
>   several queries on the XSD objects.
>   The library currently supports most
>   real-world features such as simple and
>   complex types, type restrictions and
>   attributes.